# Compare time to static value in DAX

Tags: time, dax, comparison

I have production output data that timestamps when items were completed, and I want to associate the timestamp to the shift it was made. Below is an example I'd like to show for items made between midnight and 1 am on our third shift, but I'm not sure how to format the "<1:00" portion.

IF('data'[Timestamp]<01:00,"Third","Other")

Comment: Nevermind I was able to figure this out in the following way: <TIMEVALUE("01:00")